# Problema con recorrido foreach autenticacion

Tags: php

Quiero recorrer un array con mas arrays dentro en el cual contienen usuarios y contraseña para el login, pero solo me coge el primer Array. Por lo tanto solo me puedo loguear con "Manuel", el de admin no lo recorre se ve...  Es posible que no tenga bien hecha la estructura del foreach o falte algo. Soy nuevo en PHP, asi que voy un poco perdido, si me pegan un empujoncito la verdad que se agradeceria...

Un saludo

La funcion usuariovalidado() hace lo siguiente ->

> ```
>  function usuariovalidado($user){
>              
>             return preg_match('/[a-z]/i',  $user);
>         }
> ```

```
> <?php     require_once("functions.php");   
> require_once("usuarios.php");
> 
> 
>        $errores = "";  //Devuelve true si la variable existe y tiene un valor distinto de null, false de lo contrario.   
> if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
>       $user = $_POST['usuarioname'];
>       $password = $_POST['contraseña'];
>       //Comprueba si user y password estan vacios
>       if(!empty($user && $password)) {
>          $user = trim($user);
>          $password = trim($password);
>             if(usuariovalidado($user)) {    
>                //recorremos el array usuarios y almacenamos el valor en login
>                foreach ($users as $login ) {
>                   if ($login['usuario'] === $user) {
>                   if ($login['pwd'] === $password) {
>                      session_start();
>                      $_SESSION["usuario"] = $user;
>                      header("Location: paneladministracion.php"); 
>                   }
>                   else {
>                      $errores .=  "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos";
>                      break;
>                   }
>                   }
>                   else{
>                         $errores .=  "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos";
>                         break;
>                   }
>                }
>             }
>          else {
>             $errores .= "En el campo usuario, solo se admiten cadenas de texto";
>          }
>       }
>       else {
>          $errores .=  "Por favor rellene los campos"; 
>       }    }     
>       
>          // else {
>          //   $errores.=  "Faltan parámetros en la petición de login.";
>          // }
>       
>    
>    
> 
>    
>    
> 
> 
> ?>


> <?php
> 
>     $users = array(
>         array(
>             'usuario' => 'jaime',
>             'pwd' => '1234'
>         ),
>         array (
>             'usuario' =>  'admin',
>             'pwd' => '123456'
>         )
>     );
> 
> ?>
```

Relleno  ya que si no me salta lo de que hay mas codigo
(Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum)

Comment: Nunca había visto recorrer un foreach para validarse. ¿Dónde residen las credenciales de cada usuario (supongo que en la base de datos)? Lo correcto sería comparar el la contraseña contra el nombre de usuario usando `password_verify`

Comment: ¿Loguearte con manuel? ¿De dónde sale?

Comment: Tu problema son los `break;` que están en los `else` (de los `if`), si el primer usuario no coincide ingresa al `else`, muestra error y hace el `brake`. Podrías usar una variable inicializada con false (`$logueado = false`), y si se loguea la cambias a true. Luego fuera del foreach te fijas si está logueado o no y muestras el error.

Answer (score 0):

Es medio raro tener almacenados los usuario y su password en un arreglo, y mas que el password esté como texto plano, no es aconsejable.

Puedes hacer algo así:

Primero buscar el usuario, y luego chequeas si el password coincide. Si no encontrás el usuario o el password no coincide, seteas el mensaje de error.

```
<?php

//$usuario es el nombre de usuario ingresado.
//$password es la password ingresada por el usuario.
//$users es el arreglo donde guardas los usuarios con su password.

$logueado = false

$index = array_search($usuario, array_column($users, 'usuario'));

if($index !== false) {
    $pwd = $users[$index]['pwd']; // ó array_column($users, 'pwd')[$index];

    if($password == $pwd) {
        //credenciales correctas. TODO: completar código.
        
        $logueado = true;
    }
}

if(! $logueado) {
    $errores =  "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.";
}

?>
```

En tu pregunta agregué comentario de porque falla tu código.